# Wiring a plug onto a hardwired oven

Tags: oven, cord-and-plug

I have bought a Hisense BI5228PBUK electric integrated oven. It’s 3.3kw, has a 16amp fuse and requires a 13amp power supply.

Under the worktop, behind the oven, there is a 3 pin plug socket specially installed for the existing oven (which is also 3.3kw). This socket has an on off switch on the socket and is also wired to a large red on off switch above the worktop. The fuseboard in the house has a 32amp circuit breaker labelled “oven”, which controls the power to this plug socket.

Is it a simple case of wiring a plug onto the cable coming from the oven and plugging it in to this socket?

An electrician has quoted me a price of £80 to install the oven. If it’s just a case of wiring up a plug to the end of the oven’s power cable then I would rather do it myself!

Comment: Where on the planet is this?

Comment: United Kingdom.